# Treat non-consecutive duplicates in a column as unique

Tags: filter, google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula

Say I have data like this in one column in a Google Sheets:

```
abc
abc
def
def
abc
abc
xyz
```

I want something that will give me an output treating non-consecutive duplicates as unique, i.e.:

```
abc
def
abc
xyz
```

Using `=UNIQUE()` gives me only one instance of `abc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use filter to remove rows or columns equal to the preceding value.

```
=filter(A2:A6, A2:A6 <> A1:A5)
```

Comment: could you please explain this?

Comment: You just want to remove consecutive duplicates, so compare the range that you want to the range shifted by one and FILTER will remove any that are the same.

Comment: If someone wants to do this for entire column do `=filter(A:A, A2:A <> A1:A)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple formula (I'm sorry if it is too simple):

```
=if(A1=A2,"",A1)
```

This spreadsheet may help you see the formulas.

[Treat non-consecutive duplicates in a spreadsheet column as unique](http://abcabcdefdefabcabcxyzhttps://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t1b0bf9xM7OuVlOB4_xbhE0wc3zLHBc9aCnflZHy8Ys/edit#gid=0)

I hope it helps!

Comment: The answer above (@stark 's) is correct and better.

=FILTER(A1:A, A1:A<>A2:A)

I put it in the spreadsheet if you prefer to see it working: 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t1b0bf9xM7OuVlOB4_xbhE0wc3zLHBc9aCnflZHy8Ys/edit#gid=0

Credits to @stark